# How to reverse the order of plots or "plot for [n:-1:1] ..."

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting as follows:

```
plot for [i=1:n] word(fnames,i) ... with lines ,\
     'otherfile.csv'            ... with linepoints
```

I need `otherfile.csv` to be on top of `word(fnames,n)`, on top of `word(fnames,n-1)`, ... on top of `word(fnames,1)`, but the resulting order is just the other way around.

So I am looking for a way of either reversing the order of lines being drawn or an expression like `[i=n:-1:1]` both of which I was unable to find.

Many thanks in advance!

## Update

I accepted Erics answer below, but I will rather use `[i=n:1:-1]` as suggested by maij in a comment below for this approach does not require me to adapt the arguments of `word` occurrences in the plot command.

Comment: Bastian, may I recommend that you vote and possibly accept Eric's answer?

Comment: It is `[i=n:1:-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about?

```
plot 'otherfile.csv'                ... with linepoints,\
     for [i=1:n] word(fnames,n-i+1) ... with lines
```

Comment: Ach! you were faster than me!